# Updating tableView code from Swift 1.2 - 2.0

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, ios9

I wrote this code to edit the row style (Swift 1.2 - Xcode 6.4)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle
{


    let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Edit") { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

        let abb: AnyObject = self.frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        let editingView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("editingViewController") as! editingViewController
        editingView.abbediting = abb
        self.presentViewController(editingView, animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Edit Tapped")

        print("Edited Button Clicked")  }
    edit.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Delete") { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

        let abbDel = self.frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
        self.con?.deleteObject(abbDel)



        print("Delete Button Clicked")
    }
    delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()


   return [delete,edit]


}
```

I also set some actions, but now after I've updated to Xcode 7.0 and Swift 2.0, I've been getting errors telling me to return UITableViewCellStyle.

Can any body help me to update my code to something that works with Swift 2.0 please?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code belongs to `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath`. The `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` needs to return editing style for the row, for example `UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete`. It is the style that shows when you tap the Edit button.